# VBA function works within a sub procedure but not on the excel worksheet: "value" error. Probably an issue with one argument being an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, types

I want to write a function which given 2 arguments (2 dimensional array with n rows and p columnns and a number i) it will return the i^th column of the matrix. I have written this code using an array and when I use it within a sub procedure it works but when I try to use the function on the excel worksheet I get a #value error.
Here is the function code I have written:(option base 1 because of the matrices)

```
Function extractcolumn(mat() As Variant, colnum As Integer) as variant
numrow = UBound(mat, 1)
ReDim Results(numrow, 1)

For i = 1 To numrow
    Results(i, 1) = mat(i, colnum)
Next i

extractcolumn = Results
End Function
```

which works in this sub procedure:

```
Sub testfunction()
n = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
p = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).Columns.Count
ReDim matrix(n, p)

For j = 1 To p
    For i = 1 To n
        matrix(i, j) = Cells(i, j).Value
    Next i
Next j

ret = extractcolumn(matrix, 2)
End sub
```

To solve my problem I have tried using a range as input which works both on the excel worksheet and the sub procedure but it is just not as efficient and requires more line.

```
Function extractColumn(Matrix As Range, colIndex As Integer) As Variant 
    n = Matrix.Rows.Count 'the total number of rows in the range 
    p = Matrix.Columns.Count 'the total number of columns in the range 
 ReDim result(n, 1) 

    For i = 1 To n 

        result(i, 1) = Matrix.Cells(i, colIndex).Value 

    Next i 

    extractColumn = result 

End Function
```

I would love to hear your inputs to solve my problem !

Comment: You can use a UDF in Excel only to calculate a single value, not multiple values - it is not possible to create own spill functions.

Comment: @FunThomas: that was my first thought as well - but it is not true (anymore?) the UDF spills to a range.

Comment: @Ike You're right - didn't know that. So forget my first comment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declare your argument as `Variant` or `Variant` array:

```
mat() As Variant
```

you should call this function with an array argument, not simply a range.
If you want to access a range values e.g. `A5:C7` you should write:
`+A5:C7` (universal) or
`--A5:C7` (numbers) or
`A5:C7&""` (text strings).

Answer (score 1):

Using `Index`:

```
Function extractcolumn(mat As Variant, colnum As Long) As Variant
    extractcolumn = Application.Index(mat, , colnum)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you write the range to an array performance should be better:

```vb
Function extractColumn(Matrix As Range, colIndex As Integer) As Variant

Dim arrValues As Variant
arrValues = Matrix.Value

Dim numRows As Long: numRows = UBound(arrValues)

Dim result As Variant: ReDim result(1 To numRows, 1 To 1)

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To numRows
    result(i, 1) = arrValues(i, colIndex)
Next i

extractColumn = result

End Function
```

Using `ReDim result(1 to numRows, 1 to 1)` makes `Option Base 1` obsolete.